# Inserting text in a 'find' command search

Tags: linux, awk, replace

I have a find string that finds all the instances of a particular filename in a path, like so:

```
find /opt/logs* -type f -name "deploy.log" -exec ls {} \;
```

I need to return the result with 'FINENAME=' prepended on each line. Having a hard time figuring the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /opt/logs* -type f -name deploy.log | sed 's/^/FILENAME=/'
```

Note that if you have a directory named `/opt/logs` (and you're not trying to look in `/opt/logs-foo/` and `/opt/logs-date`, or the like) you can drop the * and write `find /opt/logs -type ...`

Comment: This would not preserve newlines in the filenames. ;)

Comment: No, but the desired result ("prepended on each line") is somewhat ambiguous in that case.

Comment: imho it makes no sense that a filename with a newline character appears as `FILENAME=line1` ... `FILENAME=line2` in output. Sorry for being pedantic.. :)

Comment: Thanks William! That works brilliantly.

@hek2mgl Not sure I fully understand what you're saying but basically what I'm doing is searching for duplicate files in a directory structure and then returning their location. I need the 'FILENAME=' tacked on as the inventory will be loaded into a searchable data store and need a key value pair for later retrieval if that makes sense. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-printf` option:

```
find /opt/logs* -type f -name "deploy.log" -printf='FILENAME=%p\n'
```

`%p` will get expanded to the file's name.

Comment: Hmmm, feeling guilty that my sed solution was accepted.  Although filtering through sed is an extremely useful technique that everyone should be familiar with, this is the better solution.

Comment: Judgement day will come and the world will be ruled by files having newlines in their names! :)